# How do I reconnect my redownloaded project to an existing Github repo?

Tags: r, github, repo

I recently had some computer trouble that led to all of the files on my desktop being deleted without recovery, one of which was an R project that was feeding into a Github repo. I was able to redownload that project through the repo itself, but I don't know how to reconnect the project from my computer to the existing repo, as R just seems to want to make an entirely new repo. I apologize if this was a poor explanation, as I am relatively new to this.

Comment: Hi, if you use RStudio, you should be able to recreate the R project with `File - New project... - Version control - Git` and insert git repo. If you _cloned_ the repo, choose `File - New project... - Existing directory`. If you only downloaded the repo manually, rather delete that and choose one of the options above.

Comment: @PetrKajzar Ah okay thank you!!